# How to force 2G/3G/4G?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, moto-x

I recently moved from Note 2 to Moto X. In Note 2, the 'Mobile Networks' page inside Settings had the 'Network Mode' setting with options: **GSM/WCDMA (Auto mode), GSM only or WCDMA only**.

In Moto X however, instead of 'Network Mode' there is 'Prefered network type' which has the options: **4G (recommended), 3G or 2G**.

Through this I can force 2G, I'm assuming, but not 3G or 4G (there's no 4G in India yet anyway).

Is there any other setting or any app that can force only 3G (or 4G)?

Comment: Hello, here http://www.feelzdroid.com/2015/08/how-to-force-android-phone-to-use-3g-wcdma-mode.html is the brief explanation of what explained above with screenshot. This work for all networks like vodafone, BSNL, airtel etc...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `*#*#4636#*#*` in your dial pad (type the * and # also). Under `Phone information` you will find `Preferred network type`. Select `GSM`  or `WCDMA` from there.

You will find

1. `WCDMA preferred` this will use both 2g and 3g whichever has the
   better reception
2. `WCDMA only` this will use only 3g
3. `GSM only` this will use only 2g

Comment: If any one are trying this in dual SIM Moto G, the secret menu is applicable for SIM1 only.

Comment: Priceless. Locked the network to lte or wcdma only. I thought selecting the option in CyanogenMod would make it stick but it still went back to edge and sometimes GPRS. This time, its locked for Good.

Comment: Methods to manage mobile network settings: http://www.technewstoday.com/21776-how-to-force-a-3g-signal-on-any-android-phone/

Comment: You saved my cell phone. I was suffering two weeks with this problem. I was not able to use 3G. This tip was incredible.

Comment: Already added to favorites

Answer (score -1):

Install [Network](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mangelow.network) app  and try the option WCDMA only.